# How to publish Windows Forms Control Library with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I believe this is a question for beginners and I apologize if it was not asked in a right way. I use **Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.2.2**

The steps I take are:

1. In the Start Window that asks me "What would you like to do?" I select **Create a new project**. This takes me to a new window "Create a new project".
2. In the search field(Search for templates (Alt+S)) I enter "**Windows Forms Control**" and choose first result. The first result for me is: "C# **Windows Forms Control Library(.NET Framework)** A project for creating controls to use in Windows Forms(WinForms) applications". and then I click Next.
3. I click Create because for this question a name or anything else is not something that I have changed. That means(for me) that "Place solution and project in the same directory" is unchecked and that I use .NET Framework 4.7.2
4. After the project is opened I go to the Build option in the menu and look for the "Publish Solution" option but there is none.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to publish this(Windows Forms Control Library with Visual Studio 2022) or I just use .dll when I am finished ?
2. If it is not possible to publish or it is not possible to create some kind of executable file from Windows Forms Control Library why I am able to drag and drop controls like buttons and text fields and with that create some kind of UI?
3. If it is possible to publish please tell me how?
4. Is there some kind of list what we can publish or not when using visual studio?

Additional explanation: I followed this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/walkthrough-windows-forms-designer?view=vs-2022 and then at the end  of this article there is a "Next steps" part where it says:

> This article has demonstrated how to construct the user interface for
> a simple calculator. To continue, you can extend its functionality by
> implementing the calculator logic, then [publish the app using
> ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-the-publish-wizard?view=vs-2022). Or, continue on to a different tutorial where you create a
> picture viewer using Windows Forms.

And I followed the article that is behind the link "publish the app using ClickOnce" and tried to publish.
After some research(more than one try...) I have decided to ask a question here...

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: There is no universal standard way to do this.  Publishing a nuget package is popular, copying the DLL by hand is simple, everybody starts out by right-clicking the toolbox > Choose Items > Browse button.  ClickOnce makes no sense.

Comment: Hello @HansPassant I am sorry but I do not understand your comment. Can you be more clear ? "everybody starts out by right-clicking the toolbox > Choose Items > Browse button." this is for what ? ClickOnce makes no sense - for what ? Sorry but so far your comment is of no help for me but I thank you for your time.

Comment: The odds that this project template helps you accomplish what you want to do seem rather small.  Whatever it might be, you never mentioned it.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Hi @HansPassant you have read the Additional explanation link and the next link in the same section ? First link shows how to "design a calculator" let say it like that and then guides me/anyone else to implement the calculator logic and then to publish it right ? And my question is "How to publish Windows Forms Control Library with Visual Studio 2022". What am I missing so you are instruct me to see this: "The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem." ? My problem is "How to publish Windows Forms Control Library with Visual Studio 2022".

Comment: Hi @HansPassant can you be of help and tell me directly what am I doing wrong with my question, with my steps whatever but try to be clear about it ? Or is it too much to ask ?